# Using List Comprehension and formulas

Tags: python

I'm trying to use list comprehension to covert degrees in Celsius over to degrees in Fahrenheit using the formula: `c * 9/5 + 32` and I am confused as to what to do. I only got as far as outputting the list into a float.

Code so far:

```
degrees = [ 12, 21, 15, 32] 
farenheit = { float(degree) for degree in degrees } 
print(farenheit)
```

Where would I implement the formula `c * 9/5 + 32` within the code?

Comment: What you have written is a set comprehension - you used curly braces instead of square brackets

Comment: `[float(degree) * 9/5 + 32 for degree in degrees]`

Comment: You don't actually need to cast to `float` since the division is going to do that for you.

Comment: [item*9/5+32 for item in degrees]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I don't know why you tried to create a set instead of creating a list. Also I would say the float is unnecessary unless this is for visual purposes which I highly doubt.

```
degrees = [ 12, 21, 15, 32] 
fahrenheit = [degree * 9/5 + 32 for degree in degrees]
print(fahrenheit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `map` function:

```
celsius=[12,21,15,32]
farenheit=list(map(lambda c: c*9/5+32,celsius))
print(farenheit)
```